# UIDocumentPickerViewController - All files grayed out

Tags: ios, ios8

I'm testing the new `UIDocumentPickerViewController` API in iOS 8. I want to just open a file in iCloud, to see how the interaction works.

This is the code I'm running from my `UIViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)openDocument:(id)sender {
    [self showDocumentPickerInMode:UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];
}

- (void)showDocumentPickerInMode:(UIDocumentPickerMode)mode {
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *picker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[(NSString *)kUTTypeData] inMode:mode];

    picker.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

`openDocument` is tied to a button in IB. When I tap it, it opens the iCloud browser, but every folder in it is grayed out (I created some test Keynote, Numbers and Pages files) so I cannot get to the files:

[image: Document Picker with files grayed out].

I checked some documentation and did the following (with no luck):

- Enabled iCloud in my app (in the Capabilities section, for both Key-value storage and iCloud Documents).
- Added the UTI for `public.data` in my Info.plist as follows:

  ```
  <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
  ```

  CFBundleTypeIconFile
          icon.png
          CFBundleTypeName
          MyData
          CFBundleTypeRole
          Viewer
          LSItemContentTypes
          
              public.data
          
          LSTypeIsPackage
          
          NSDocumentClass
          Document
          NSPersistentStoreTypeKey
          Binary
- Added the `NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic` key with a value of `YES` to my Info.plist.

Any idea what could be wrong or missing?

Comment: Your image doesn't show grayed out files.  What happens if you open the folder(s)?

Comment: The folder(s) are grayed out, I cannot get to the files. Just added a clarification.

Comment: @pgbHave u tested with beta 3 release?

Comment: @karan not yet. I can't link my project with the latest Xcode...

Comment: @pgb thanks for your reply. I am also working with UIDocumentPickerViewController in my app.I followed above steps but when presenting UIDocumentPicker app get crash with error "icloud entittlement missing for uidocumentpicker". I enable icloud to my project. Can you test your project with latest beta?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

iWork documents do not conform to `kUTTypeData`, they conform to `kUTTypePackage`.

However, in iOS 8 beta 3, I had to use the exact UTIs:

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *picker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", @"com.apple.iwork.keynote.key"] inMode:mode];
```

Comment: Seems to occur in beta 4 as well

Comment: It occurs in beta 5 as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How did you know the UTIs of Apple's own apps? Is that published somewhere? Thanks again!

Comment: You can use the `mdls` command to see the UTI of a file. iWork files created on the Mac also have ZIP file format, but files saved in iCloud seem to always use the package format.

Comment: When I use these UTIs, the iWork folders become openable, but  upon tapping on a file nothing happens. I have implemented documentPicker didPickDocumentAtURL and it is not being called

Comment: Here is a list of common UTIs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1 . It references constants found in MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h which can be used instead of typing the UTI string.

Answer (score 24):

```
**Swift 3+ Solution**
```

Will open and provide access to all items on drive.

```
//open document picker controller

func openImportDocumentPicker() {
    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.item"], in: .import)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}
/*
 *
 * Handle Incoming File
 *
 */

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
    if controller.documentPickerMode == .import {
        let alertMessage: String = "Successfully imported \(url.absoluteURL)"
   }
}
/*
 *
 * Cancelled
 *
 */

func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
    print("Cancelled")
}
```

Comment: Correct. Thank you!

Comment: Glad ! Could help you .

Comment: Public faking item!