# UIDocumentPickerViewController & iCloud entitlement in IOS 8

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I have a document based app in App Store. Now I am trying to use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in my app to share the file from my app `UIDocumentProviderExtension` supported apps.

Previously I have used `UIDocumentInteractionController` to transfer files between apps. The problem is when I used `UIDocumentPickerViewController`, I got the error "iCloud entitlement missing" in app.

According to the Apple document, I need to add the iCloud entitlement if my app supports the iCloud storage, but it's not a requirement for my app. So, I want to understand what is the need of iCloud entitlement for presenting `UIDocumentPickerViewController`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497213/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller-all-files-grayed-out

Answer (score 1):

the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` allows your app to access the shared iCloud documents even if your app does not support iCloud document storage itself. This is the default behavior of the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

So if you want to use the `UIDocumentPickerViewController` you have to add iCloud entitlement to your App ID.

If not, you might want to create an `DocumentProviderExtension` in your app. Then you don't need to add the iCloud entitlement to your app id and your users can access your documents from within their  preferred app (which has a `UIDocumentPickerViewController`).