# UIDocumentPickerViewController import SSL Certificate

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickervc

How can I import a SSL Certificate using `UIDocumentPickerViewController`?

I'm doing something like this:

```
let documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.item"], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.import)
documentPicker.delegate = self
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
}

UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .green
self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: completion)
```

But the `.cer` file is always disable to select it:

[image: cer disabled]

Also, I can't find a way to import files without extension.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42142790/1361672

Comment: @Ercell0 it still not working that answer

Comment: are you accessing the file with url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() and url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() in didPickDocumentAtURL, you can also use NSFileCoordinator to access the file as well.

Comment: @Ercell0 No, because I can't select the file because is the file is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I make it works. First, I had to import mobile core services:

```
import MobileCoreServices
```

Then, this is how I instantiate the `UIDocumentPickerViewController`:

```
let types: NSArray = NSArray(object: kUTTypeX509Certificate as NSString)
let documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: types as! [String], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.import)
```

By the way, I only make it works with `iCloud Drive`, it doesn't work with `Google Drive` apparently by a bug: http://www.openradar.me/24187873